# Trying to embed a controller in a template

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to embed the login form of FOSUserBundle in a template with
this:

```
{% render "FOSUserBundle::Security::login" %}
```

but I'm getting this:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Class "FOSUserBundle" does not exist.") in
>   "AibFrontendBundle:General:home.html.twig" at line 6.

I have tried also this:

```
{% render "UserBundle::Security::login" %}
```

but the error is the same (An exception has been thrown during the
rendering of a template ("Class "UserBundle" does not exist.").

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead (single `:` after the bundle name):

```
{% render "FOSUserBundle:Security:login" %}
```

This short notation expands to `FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController::loginAction`. The double colon separates class name from method name.

Comment: Thanks @igorw, but doesn't work..An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Class "FOSUserBundle:Security" does not exist.")

Comment: My bad, it needs a single colon after `Security` as well. Fixed my example.

Comment: Thanks, works, I duplicated the ":" in the controller notation. Class::method is the way to call a controller represented by a static method of a class and your call is detected as being this sort of call.

Comment: Yeah, this short notation actually expands to: `FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController::loginAction`.